# How to Rename a File from English to Other Language?

Tags: excel, vba

I really hope someone can help me with this because I need to do,

I have an excel file with some columns and one column having file name in English and other column having the filename in other language.
Now i need to do is rename the file in other language, is it possible to rename.

I tried this code

```
Sub pdfrenamefile()
Dim oldfile As String
Dim nwfile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim fname As Range
Set rng = Range("Y7", Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each fname In rng
    If IsEmpty(fname) Or fname = "" Then
    'do nothing
    Else
        If FileFolderExists(Cells(1, 1) & fname) Then
            nwfile = fname.Offset(, 1) & ".PDF"
            Name Cells(1, 1) & fname As Cells(1, 1) & nwfile
            fname.Offset(0, 2) = nwfile
            fname.Offset(0, 3) = "Success"
        Else
            Range("AB" & fname.Row) = "File Not Found"
        End If
    End If
Next fname
End Sub
```

Example :

Sample Data ID OldFileName NewFileName

```
1 Sales1.PDF తెలుగు1.PDF   
2 Sales02.PDF తెలుగు02.PDF   
3 Sales567.PDF తెలుగు567.PDF   
4 dest67.PDF తెలుగు67.PDF
```

I tried but it converting only into english, but not accepting to other.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You aren't showing any code of what you tried. Share what you are trying to do ... and a sample of the data as well.

Comment: Thank You Masud for quick response 
The Code is
Sub pdfrenamefile()
Dim oldfile As String
Dim nwfile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim fname As Range
Set rng = Range("Y7", Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each fname In rng
If IsEmpty(fname) Or fname = "" Then
Else
    If FileFolderExists(Cells(1, 1)&fname) Then
        nwfile = fname.Offset(, 1)&".PDF"
        Name Cells(1, 1)&fname As Cells(1, 1) & nwfile
        fname.Offset(0, 2)=nwfile
        fname.Offset(0, 3)="Success"
    Else
       Range("AB"&fname.Row)="File Not Found"
    End If
    End If
Next fname
End Sub

Comment: Please Add the code to the QUESTION so that it's actually readable. This code asis is not usable anywhere :(

Comment: Sample Data
ID OldFileName NewFileName 
1 Sales1.PDF తెలుగు1.PDF
2 Sales02.PDF తెలుగు02.PDF
3 Sales567.PDF తెలుగు567.PDF
4 dest67.PDF తెలుగు67.PDF

Comment: Please tell us more precisely what goes wrong, what doesn't work, what did you expect or whatever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made the minimum changes to your code to make it work.  However, I find your code confusing so I also recommended some further changes.

I had to place your sample data in range X6:Z10 so the first old file name was in cell Y7.

I had to place the name of the folder holding the files in cell A1.

I hope the reasons for my changes are clear.  Ask if they are not.

```
Sub pdfrenamefile()

  Dim oldfile As String
  Dim nwfile As String
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim fname As Range

  ' I find your names confusing.  For example, You should rename fname to make
  ' clear that it is a range.  You have declared oldname but do now use it. 

  ' You are using methods that require a file system object
  Dim fso As Object
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set rng = Range("Y7", Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

  ' You use too many different methods of located cells.  You use 
  ' rng.Offset(0, c), Cells(r, c) and "AB" & r.  Will you understand this
  ' code in six months?  What if you decide to change the position of the
  ' table of names?

  For Each fname In rng

    ' fname is a range.  fname.Value is its value.
    If IsEmpty(fname.Value) Or fname.Value = "" Then
    Else
      ' I have replaced "FileFolderExist" by "fso.FileExists".
      ' "Cells(1, 1)" is acceptable but I prefer "Cells(1, 1).Value"
      ' which makes absolutely clear you want the value.   
      If fso.FileExists(Cells(1, 1).Value & fname.Value) Then
        ' You already have the extension in the worksheet so
        ' do not need to add ".PDF".
        nwfile = fname.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ' You check the old file exists but not that the new file
        ' does not exist.  I have added another If-Then-Else-End If.
        If fso.FileExists(Cells(1, 1) & nwfile) Then
          Range("AB" & fname.Row) = nwfile & " already exists"
        Else
          ' The Name statement will not accept non-English letters.
          ' I have used MoveFile which will accept non-English letters. 
          ' "fname.Value" not "fname" because "fname" is a range.
          fso.movefile Cells(1, 1).Value & fname.Value, _
                                                   Cells(1, 1).Value & nwfile
          ' You have nwfile in Offset(0,1).  Why duplicate it?
          fname.Offset(0, 2) = nwfile
          fname.Offset(0, 3) = "Success"
        End If
      Else
        ' I have added the old name to the message to make clear
        ' what has not been found.
        Range("AB" & fname.Row) = fname.Value & " not found"
      End If
    End If
  Next fname

End Sub
```

Comment: desserves the +1 for improving this code (and trying to understand the question :))

Comment: Thank you so much Tony Dallimore. Its working fine. Actually what i need to do is renaming the file with non english letters i.e. some other language. Your modified code is working good. I have one doubt the non english file names will be displayed as it is (i.e. in Non English) or displays in symbols. To display it as it is (Non English not symbols) what i need to do. Thank you for help...

Comment: I renamed dummy files using your names and their appearance was correct with the same shapes as in your example.  I believe Windows will allow any letter in any alphabet to be used in a file name.  The only problem was they were in a very small font so they were difficult to read.  I am sure there is a way of making them bigger but I do not know what it is.

Comment: Hi Tony Thank you for you response.
Another question, I have some text files with tab delimited in a folder. The text file having 1st line as column headings. I am able to import into excel file. But where the text file is not same as the excel template, it is not required to import. How to limit it. 
Is there any code to do this.